# My old patented invention appears to be patented again

Tags: prior-art, inventorship, invalidation, process, us8384613

In reference to the patent: [US 8,384,613](https://www.google.com/patents/US8384613)

What one has to do, if this patent is not new and just gives the same idea patented in 1990?

I would be grateful on an answer.

Comment: Do you know the publication number for your patent?

Answer (score 2):

Any claim that covers embodiments rendered obvious by the description of the previous patent is invalid.

At first glance it appears that the newer patent adds a lot of constraints to the structure; these additional constraints might not be obvious even if the purpose of the invention is the same.

Just because a car has already been patented doesn't mean you can't patent a car. You can still patent a car that has specifics to it that are not rendered obvious by any previously described car. You just can't patent a car *at the same level of generality* anymore.